# What is the Ancient Vampire Sword for in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, mod-identification

A friend of mine found this sword in their inventory, and it is marked as a quest item. It is in the Miscellaneous section, however, rather than weapons. We believe it is from a mod, but are unsure which mod it is from, and also cannot figure out what quest it belongs to. Can anyone help?

[image: screenshot of item in the inventory in-game]

Comment: Install [this mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/23581) and it will tell you what quest owns the item (when you try to drop it).

Answer (score 1):

It's from the [Better Vampire NPCs](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/9510) mod, specifically the Coldhaven quest, and [according to the mod author](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/7289941-coldhaven-a-vampire-city/page-29#entry72602748) is in the game as a quest item (hence in the Miscellaneous section) because:

> "*One of the houses wants you to retrieve it.*"